# How to retrieve a value already initialized in an associative array

Tags: javascript

I wish I didn't have to rewrite some things that could just be copied from a variable in an associative array created.

That is my code, but I got an error that says *title is not defined* :

```
const shopLocation = {
  "uccle-heros": {
    title: "Uccle Héros Defré",
    location: [4.334562, 50.043438],
    description: '<strong>'
      + title
      + '</strong>'
      + '<p>'
      + '<a id="test" '
      + 'href="http://www.mtpleasantdc.com/makeitmtpleasant" '
      + 'target="_blank" '
      + 'title="Opens in a new window">'
      + 'Make it Mount Pleasant</a>'
      + 'is a handmade and vintage market and afternoon of live '
      + 'entertainment and kids activities. 12:00-6:00 p.m.'
      + '</p>'
  }
};
```

Comment: How did you call the `title` key?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
const shopLocation = {
  "uccle-heros": {
    title: "Uccle Héros Defré",
    location: [4.334562, 50.043438],
    get description() {
      return '<strong>' + this.title + '</strong><p><a id="test" href="http://www.mtpleasantdc.com/makeitmtpleasant" target="_blank" title="Opens in a new window">Make it Mount Pleasant</a> is a handmade and vintage market and afternoon of live entertainment and kids activities. 12:00-6:00 p.m.</p>'
    }
  }
};

console.log(shopLocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Spectric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70039243/467473), use *interpolated strings*. Much more readable:

```js
const shopLocation = {
  "uccle-heros": {
    title: "Uccle Héros Defré",
    location: [4.334562, 50.043438],
    get description() {
      return `
        <strong>${this.title}</strong>
        <p>
          <a
            id="test"
            href="http://www.mtpleasantdc.com/makeitmtpleasant"
            target="_blank"
            title="Opens in a new window"
          >
            Make it Mount Pleasant
          </a>
          is a handmade and vintage market and afternoon
          of live entertainment and kids activities.
          12:00-6:00 p.m.
        </p>`
    }
  }
};

console.log(shopLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of this is called an object in javascript

secondly in order to reference something nested in a nested object like this you have to call it as such `shopLocation['uccle-heros'].title`